# Wikitude - I can't use external web service link

Tags: wikitude

I'm using Wikitude as my augmented reality mobile app project. My question is why can't I use external web service link? Is it because of trial version?

I'm using this sample from https://github.com/Wikitude/wikitude-phonegap-samples/tree/master/PluginSamples/www/world/5_BrowsingPois_3_LimitingRange

limiting.js

Original source code:

```
var ServerInformation = {
    POIDATA_SERVER: "http://example.wikitude.com/GetSamplePois/",
    POIDATA_SERVER_ARG_LAT: "lat",
    POIDATA_SERVER_ARG_LON: "lon",
    POIDATA_SERVER_ARG_NR_POIS: "nrPois"
};
```

Edited source code:

```
var ServerInformation = {
    POIDATA_SERVER: "http://staging.revivalx.com/rmbp/branch.json",
    POIDATA_SERVER_ARG_LAT: "lat",
    POIDATA_SERVER_ARG_LON: "lon",
    POIDATA_SERVER_ARG_NR_POIS: "nrPois"
};
```

Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wikitude only allowed custom external web service if we using premium version.